# Limit Question involving modulus

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left\{\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin|x|-|x|}{|x^3|}\right\}$$

I have tried by using L'Hôpital's rule, but the expression becomes very messy after successive differentiation. I also do not know how to approach a limit involving modulus (not being possible to write this as a piece wise function).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try finding the limit with the added restriction $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Do you know Taylor expansions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be looking for $a_3$ where$$e^{-x^2}\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$also we know that$$e^{-x^2}=1-x^2+\dfrac{x^4}{2}-\cdots\\\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\cdots$$therefore$$e^{-x^2}\sin x=x-\dfrac{7}{6}x^3+o(x^3)$$therefore$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin|x|-|x|}{|x^3|}=\lim_{|x|\to 0}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin|x|-|x|}{|x^3|}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\dfrac{7}{6}x^3+o(x^3)-x}{x^3}=-\dfrac{7}{6}$$